# how can i fix it this error in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-requests

I want to check the login status so. I make program to check it

```py
import requests
import json
import datetime


headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "50",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.290443894.1570500092; _gid=GA1.2.963761342.1579153496; JSESSIONID=A4B3165F23FBEA34B4BBE429D00F12DF",
    "Host": "marke.ai",
    "Origin": "http://marke",
    "Referer": "http://marke/event2/login",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Mobile Safari/537.36",
}
url = "http://mark/api/users/login"
va = {"username": "seg", "password": "egkegn"}
c = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(va), headers=headers)
if c.status_code != 200:
    print("error")
```

This is working very well in my windows local with Pycharm

but when i ran the code in Linux i got the error like this

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='marke', port=80):
Max retries exceeded with url: http://marke.ai/api/users/login (
  Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
    NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)
  )
)
```

So.. what is the problem please teach me also if you know the solution please teach me!!

thank you

Comment: it returns you a ProxyError. Are you behind a proxy ? If yes, try to specify your proxy parameters in your request

Comment: I add More information
the web site which i need to check login status  is made by spring boot jar file 
also it's running on my linux server which is same linux

Answer (score 1):

According to your error, it seems you are behind a proxy.

So you have to specify your proxy parameters when building your request.

Build your proxies as a dict following this format

```py
proxies = {
    "http": "http://my_proxy:my_port",
    "https": "https://my_proxy:my_port"
}
```

If you don't know your proxy parameters, then you can get them using `urllib` module :

```py
import urllib
proxies = urllib.request.getproxies()
```

Comment: c = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(va), headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

Comment: proxies = urllib.request.getproxies()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: import urllib.request

Comment: @hognkun happens sometimes with this module, please refer to @Sreeragh A R workaround and use ```import urllib.request``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's a proxy server configured on that Linux host, and it can't connect to it.

Judging by [the documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies), you may have a `PROXY_URL` environment variable set.

Comment: i alsoo try it but i don't understand well so the proxy_url is my linux host ip or web url?!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @Arkenys answer. Please try this.

```
import urllib.request
proxies = urllib.request.getproxies()

# all other things

c = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(va), headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```